# Рисование структурой RGBQUAD

Tags: c++, c, рисование

Нашёл исходники, где рисуют графику с нуля (по пикселям), там используется структура `RGBQUAD`.

Четвёртый параметр структуры `rgbReserved`, вычитал что с его помощью можно задать alpha-канал, но не особо получилось.

Как помощью этой структуры задать alpha-канал пикселю, который рисую?

И мог бы я чисто теоретически создать собственный велосипед с alpha-каналом? Если да, то подтолкните — с чего начать, формулы не нашёл, алгоритма нету, в основном из наставлений сплошные туториалы по фотошопу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем сам решил.
`RGBQUAD` просто структура,такая же как и если я создам свою.

нужна структура `BITMAPINFO` и функция вывода на экран `SetDIBitsToDevice`. А дальше просто творить,манипулируя битами.